# Calculate normals

Tags: java, lwjgl, normals

I loaded a heightmap from a bmp picture and drew it. But the lights do not work because it doesn't have normals. How do you calculate the normals from 3 vertex?
(I saw a C++ question here but I cannot do it in Java)

Comment: Can you link to the C++ question at least?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13889461/normals-for-height-map-data?rq=1

Comment: Why don't you just convert the code by hand from C++ to java? Math is math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using OpenGL (or JOGL) at all?? The link you posted involves using functions in OpenGL for cross products and normalization.  That being said, these functions are easy enough to do out step by step.

Here's the math:
 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305642/how-to-find-surface-normal-of-a-triangle